# Why is it not possible to install the plugin launcheffect for wordpress on red hats openshift?

Tags: php, wordpress, cloud, redhat, openshift

I am trying this out:
I want to install http://launcheffectapp.com/download/ on openshift.

But when I try under plugins to upload the *.zip file I only get:

> Installing Plugin from uploaded file: launcheffect_lite_2.2.zip
>
> Unpacking the package…
>
> Installing the plugin…
>
> The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.
>
> Plugin install failed.

Why is that not possible?

I appreciate your answer!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have tried to install the package as a plugin; It needs to be installed as a theme, please follow below instructions:

In your WordPress admin, go to Appearance > Themes. On that screen, click the tab that says, "Install Themes". In the menu directly below the tab, click "Upload". Upload the ZIP folder. Upon completion click "Activate". A Launch Effect menu should have appeared as the last menu group on the left.

I was able to successfully install the theme on my wordpress site hosted on openshift.

```
Installing Theme from uploaded file: launcheffect_lite_2.2.zip
Unpacking the package...
Installing the theme...
Theme installed successfully.
```